# c++ copy control issue

Tags: c++, string, pointers, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class HasPtr{
 public:
    //constructor accepts a string
    HasPtr(const string &s = string()) : ps(new string(s)), i(0), use(new size_t(1)) {}  
    //copy constructor
    HasPtr(const HasPtr &h) : ps(h.ps), i(h.i), use(h.use) { ++*use; }
    //copy assignment operator 
    HasPtr &operator=(const HasPtr &h)
    {
        ++*h.use;
        if(--*use == 0)
        {
            delete ps;
            delete use;
        }
        ps = h.ps;
        i = h.i;
        use = h.use;

        return *this;
    }
    ~HasPtr()
    {
        if(--*use == 0)
        {
            delete ps;
            delete use;
        }
    }

//private:
    string *ps;
    int i;

    size_t *use;
};


int main()
{
    HasPtr h("hi mom");
    HasPtr h2 = h;
    HasPtr h3("hi dad");
    h2 = h3;

    cout << "h: " << *h.ps << endl;
    cout << "h2: " << *h2.ps << endl;
    cout << "h3: " << *h3.ps << endl;
}
```

**The output is:**

```
h: hi mom
h2: hi dad
h3: hi dad
```

**I think the output should be:**

```
h: hi dad
h2: hi dad
h3: hi dad
```

**The reason why I think the output should like above:**

h is "hi mom", h2 shares h1, so h2 is "hi mom", h3 is "hi dad", and I think `h2 = h3` changed h1 either because h2 shares h1, but it's not.

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?`: Using pointers. If you use objects all this goes away. Also there is already a reference counted smart pointer `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: `h2 = h3` does not affect `h1` at all. You're not modifying *what's pointed to*, but *the pointers stored in `h2`*. Compare to: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c380c6c80e66a393

Comment: For future reference, you may want to read about the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) and [the Big Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). As stated by @LokiAstari, you probably also just want to use the builtin `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: h2 shares h1 up until the point where you assign to h2. This is classic reference counting - the semantics are as if you were dealing with simple value objects, but copies are deferred until they are really needed. A nice idea, but in practice not a win, especially if you are using multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That it would be more clear let's consider a simplified example

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;

int *h = &x;
int *h2 = h;
```

Now `h` and `h2` point to `x`. You can check this outputting the object pointed to by the pointers. For example

```
std::cout << "*h = " << *h << ", *h2 = " << *h2 << std::endl;
```

Then you are using the third pointer

```
int *h3 = &y;
h2 = h3;
```

Now `h2` and `h3` point to `y`. `h` was not changed. You also can check this

```
std::cout << "*h2 = " << *h2 << ", *h3 = " << *h3 << std::endl;
std::cout << "*h = " << *h << std::endl;
```

The same occurs with your objects in statements

```
HasPtr h("hi mom");
HasPtr h2 = h;
HasPtr h3("hi dad");
h2 = h3;
```

only corresponding pointers (ps) are wrapped in the objects of the class.

Here is a program that demonstrates the explanation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string hi_mom( "hi mom" );
    std::string hi_dad( "hi dad" );

    std::string *h  = &hi_mom;
    std::string *h2 = h;

    std::cout << "*h = " << *h << ", *h2 = " << *h2 << std::endl;

    std::string *h3 = &hi_dad;
    h2 = h3;

    std::cout << "*h2 = " << *h2 << ", *h3 = " << *h3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*h = " << *h << std::endl;
}
```

Its output is

```
*h = hi mom, *h2 = hi mom
*h2 = hi dad, *h3 = hi dad
*h = hi mom
```

Comment: Thank you, could you give me an example of corresponding pointers?

Comment: @XIAOD "Corresponding pointers" are the data member ps declared like string *ps; of the corresponding objects h, h2 and h3. In fact the class is simply a wrapper around this pointer, In my example I removed the wrapper leaving only the pointers themselves and naming them the same way as the names of the objects..

Answer (score 3):

Here's whats going on:

```
HasPtr h("hi mom");
HasPtr h2 = h;

h.ps ---> "hi mom"  <--- h2.ps
```

Then with the next statement, you change `h2` but that doesn't affect `h`:

```
HasPtr h3("hi dad");
h2 = h3;

h2.ps ----> "hi dad" <--- h3.ps
 |
XXX changed
 |
"hi mom" <--- h.ps
```

The pointers are different instances that point to the same address. Example:

```
int a = 5, c = 1; 
int *p1 = &a, *p2 = &a;
```

Changing `p1` (ie `p1 = &c`) won't affect `p2`.

Comment: still don't get it. h2 has the same pointer as h1. If h2 changes, why doesn't h1 changes?

Comment: @XIAODI The pointers are different instances that point to the same address. Example: `int a = 5; int *p1 = &a, *p2 = &a`. Changing `p1` (ie `p1 = &c`) won't affect `p2`